# solving singular matrix

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, singularity

Hello I have a matrix that is singular, and i wanted to use linear solve to solve it but that doesn't work with mathematica. 
The matrix given as a list looks like this:

```
matrix={{-4.41583, 0.203293, 0.447379, 0.7368, 0.960962, 0.968754, 0.699615, 
  0.318076, 0.0744302, 0.00652486}, {0.203293, -18.8705, 1.83288, 
  3.08607, 4.14357, 4.33257, 3.27222, 1.57047, 0.392219, 
  0.0371938}, {0.447379, 1.83288, -47.3538, 7.34906, 10.3619, 11.5218,
   9.3836, 4.93348, 1.3749, 0.148821}, {0.7368, 3.08607, 
  7.34906, -97.4412, 20.4672, 24.839, 22.5198, 13.4792, 4.39045, 
  0.573605}, {0.960962, 4.14357, 10.3619, 20.4672, -180.403, 46.1487, 
  48.173, 34.1909, 13.6695, 2.28682}, {0.968754, 4.33257, 11.5218, 
  24.839, 46.1487, -308.446, 90.4891, 79.5771, 41.1696, 
  9.39975}, {0.699615, 3.27222, 9.3836, 22.5198, 48.173, 
  90.4891, -486.648, 160.313, 113.766, 38.0322}, {0.318076, 1.57047, 
  4.93348, 13.4792, 34.1909, 79.5771, 160.313, -695.231, 261.979, 
  138.87}, {0.0744302, 0.392219, 1.3749, 4.39045, 13.6695, 41.1696, 
  113.766, 261.979, -834.853, 398.036}, {0.00652486, 0.0371938, 
  0.148821, 0.573605, 2.28682, 9.39975, 38.0322, 138.87, 
  398.036, -587.391}}//MatrixForm

b={14.1067,14.,13.8203,13.5647,13.2288,12.8062,12.2882,11.6619,10.9087,10.};
```

I wanted to solve this using:

```
LinearSolve[matrix,b]
```

However this doesn't work, so does anyone have any alternative suggestions for methods of solving this equations?

Comment: Your problem is the use of `MatrixForm` in defining `matrix`.  Remove it, and I think you'll have your answer.

Comment: See [Basic Syntax Issues](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/57).

Comment: Actually saying where it has been asked before would be useful perhaps, don't you think?